# Connect-AzureRmAccount - Cannot connect to Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

While trying to connect Azure from Powershell getting below error:

```
PS H:\> Connect-AzureRmAccount
Connect-AzureRmAccount : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Comment: have you tried to use Connect-AzureRmAccount -debug 
to seethe detailed errors ?

Comment: It is kind of not related but `AzureRM` is deprecated and if possible you should try to use `Az` powershell module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0. At least if you re starting a new project :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to try :

Sometime , powershell cmdlet doesn't give proper error message as it suppressed it , to get the actual error you can try executing with -debug attribute or you can try using [DebugPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#debugpreference) like below.

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
Write-Debug -Message "Hello, World"
```

Alternatively ,Connect-AzureRMAccount cmdlet used TLS 1.0 by default for connecting to azure and sometime it gets blocked by the organization security policy,

Can you setting up something like below:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Additional reference:

[Connect-AzureRmAccount : accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331071/connect-azurermaccount-accessing-ws-metadata-exchange-failed)

Hope it helps.